# Why does France have so many bilateral treaties?

Tags: international-relations, france, treaty

According to Miles & Posner (2008) ["Which States Enter into Treaties, and Why?"](https://chicagounbound.uchicago.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1622&context=law_and_economics)

> The average for North
>   America is more than ten times that of Africa. The North American average is driven by the
>   United States, which is party to 7,181 bilateral treaties. **The next most active nation, France,
>   is party to 3,707 bilateral treaties**. The third most active, Spain, is party to 2,527 bilateral
>   treaties, and China is the fourth most active with 2,490 bilateral treaties. North America has
>   nearly five times the average number of bilateral treaties with states as the second-ranked
>   continent (Europe). The average state has entered 463 bilateral treaties.

**Is there a qualitative explanation why France has substantially more bilateral treaties than other EU countries?** (The paper doesn't offer it.) I can think of former colonies, Canada etc., but then Spain or the UK also had colonies etc. So why does France have so many bilateral treaties?

Comment: I think the UK and Spain were mostly done with colonies before this data set starts in 1946 while France wasn't. I tried to follow the author's [link](http://db.lib.washington.edu/wti/wtbd.htm) to the list of bilateral treaties, but got a 404, maybe someone less lazy will find a new link to the database if it is available.

Comment: The UK has the Commonwealth, that perhaps "saves" a lot of treaties. The French attempt at a equivalent organization, the French Union, collapsed soon. Spain lost its colonies way before and the ties were always more tenuous.

Comment: @SJuan76: that sound like a reasonable answer.